# RewriteRule does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to match URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/line/s3360
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/template.php?product=s3360
```

and I do this by `RewriteRule` like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^line/(.+)/?$ line/template.php?product=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But I do not want to redirect URL:

```
http://www.example.com/line/
```

Instead I want to link this URL to

```
http://www.example.com/line/index.php
```

Full htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /erreur.php?erreur=400
ErrorDocument 401 /erreur.php?erreur=401
ErrorDocument 402 /erreur.php?erreur=402
ErrorDocument 403 /erreur.php?erreur=403
ErrorDocument 404 /erreur.php?erreur=404
ErrorDocument 405 /erreur.php?erreur=405
ErrorDocument 500 /erreur.php?erreur=500
ErrorDocument 501 /erreur.php?erreur=501
ErrorDocument 502 /erreur.php?erreur=502
ErrorDocument 503 /erreur.php?erreur=503
ErrorDocument 504 /erreur.php?erreur=504
ErrorDocument 505 /erreur.php?erreur=505

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#avoid problem with form
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)index$ $1 [R=301]

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} line/.+
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !line/ind
RewriteRule ^line/(.+)/?$ line/template.php?product=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: try adding : `RewriteRule ^line/$ line/index.php` before the specific one

Comment: That rule you posted in the question will _not_ rewrite the request URL `http://www.example.com/line/` So it looks like you have to add more details to your question. Currently it is unclear. Please post your full existing rule set inline in the question. A link to some arbitrary external site is _not_ a replacement for that here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
RewriteRule ^line\/([a-z][0-9]{4,})\/?$ template.php?product=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I had to make a guess, what could possibly stand after /line/XXXXX.

Comment: `/` doesn't need to be escaped, it's not a delimiter in htaccess.